# bitwise operator on half a byte C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project which outputs to an odd circuit and need to invert half the byte I am sending. So for example, if I am sending the number 100 as a byte, it comes out in the chip as 01100100, nice and easy. The problem is that I need it to be 10010100, i.e. the first nibble is inverted. This is because of how the outputs of the chip work.

I have playing with the ~ command doing something like:

```
int b = a & 0x0000000F;
```

This inverts the second nibble. I can also invert the whole thing with:

```
int b = a & 0x000000FF;
```

But I want to get the first nibble of the byte and

```
int b = a & 0x000000F0;
```

doesn't give me the answer I am after.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with C# in particular, you should revise your mathematical skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invert a bit, you xor (exclusive or) it.

So you have to do `a ^ 0xF0`;

Answer (score 0):

with shifting:

```
b = (byte) ((b & 0x0F) + (~(b >> 4)<<4));
```

without shifting:

```
b = (byte)((b & 0x0F) + ((~(b & 0xF0)) & 0xF0));
```

(not that shifting or not matters...)